# Singleton is always creating a new instance

Tags: java, android, singleton

I am trying to use the singleton framework for a class in my android app. When I call getInstance() it initializes fine, however when I call getInstance() in a different activity, it always creates a new instance as opposed to returning the instance already created.

```
public class LinkedList {

private static LinkedList theList;

public static LinkedList getInstance(){
    if(theList == null){
        System.out.println("New List*********************");
        return new LinkedList();
    }
    else
        return theList;
}

private LinkedList(){
    defaultPopulate();
}

}
```

I was curious if there's some small thing I'm missing because I'm new to android programming. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You never assign anything to theList, so it is always null :)

Comment: Really? You couldn't search the web for `java singleton getInstance` and find examples of how to do this????

Comment: It was just a terrible oversight by me, that's what I get for late night programming

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your getInstance method, instead of just returning a new LinkedList, you need to make sure you set theList equal to the new object you just created.

```
public static LinkedList getInstance(){
    if(theList == null){
        System.out.println("New List*********************");
        theList = new LinkedList();
    }
    return theList;
}
```

Comment: This answer is pretty Sharp (no pun intended) +1

Answer (score 1):

There are various types with you implement singleton instance

1. Eager initialization:

In eager initialization, the instance of Singleton Class is created at the time of class loading, this is the easiest method to create a singleton class.

```
public class SingletonClass {

    private static volatile SingletonClass sSoleInstance = new SingletonClass();

    //private constructor.
    private SingletonClass(){}

    public static SingletonClass getInstance() {
        return sSoleInstance;
     }
}
```

2. Lazy initialization:

This method will check if there is any instance of that class is already created? If yes, then our method (getInstance()) will return that old instance and if not then it creates a new instance of the singleton class in JVM and returns that instance

```
public class SingletonClass {

    private static SingletonClass sSoleInstance;

    private SingletonClass(){}  //private constructor.

    public static SingletonClass getInstance(){
        if (sSoleInstance == null){ //if there is no instance available... create new one
            sSoleInstance = new SingletonClass();
        }

       return sSoleInstance;
   }
}
```

There are also few more this which will need to take in consideration like **Java Reflection API**, **Thread Safe & Serialization safe** Singleton.

This Blogpost contains various Singleton design patterns, it will be helpful to take a look at this https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/digesting-singleton-design-pattern-in-java-5d434f4f322#.mclooglq8

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14897457)

Comment: @DeepakMahakale thanks for you valuable review i will update the answer.